# Make <div> with childs always fit in parent <div>

Tags: html, css, scale

I'm trying to make a div with some children inside always fit to the parent div which covers the whole page. It already works that the child div's width fits into the parent's. But the height should also fit inside the parent div. I want to avoid using `overflow: auto` because then the user will have to scroll in some cases. The child div (with it's children inside) should always fit in the parent's height and width.

How can I make this in CSS?

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <button>Toggle</button>
        <img />
        <p>Some text here...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `<div class="parent">` covers the whole page. The `<div class="child">` should scale into the `<div class="parent">` width and height.

Comment: What do you want to happen if the content inside child is to big to fit within parent? Do you want parent to grow, or ??

Comment: @MTilsted I want the content to be scaled down to fit inside the parent, always.

Comment: @RobertoZvjerković I‘ve tried that already and it’s not working. The child div fits with it‘s with inside the parent but the height is bigger than the screen.

Comment: Do you mean that you want the font size to become smaller so the text fits inside the device window regardless of the screen size? I cna only think to do that with javascript. Check if the text fits, if not, make the font smaller, check if it fits, loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.  You would need a media query for mobile but does what I think you are asking...

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      font-weight: 400;
      background-color: black;
      color: white;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      margin: 0;
    }

    .grid {
      min-height: 100%;
      grid-column: 1 / -1;
      grid-gap: 0;
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(33%, 1fr));
    }

    .grid>span {
      flex: 1;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
    }

    .image {
      background-image: url('https://live.staticflickr.com/7206/6859864719_5d68aedbd7.jpg');
      background: cover;
      background-position: center center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }

    .toggle {
      background: #4096C0;
      border-radius: 2px;
      padding: 12px 24px;
      color: white;
      width: auto;
      text-align: center;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .toggle:hover {
      background: #00537C;
    }


    .text {
      background: #40B6C0;
      padding: 72px;
      color: white;
    }

  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="grid">

      <span class="toggle">TOGGLE</span>
      <span class="image"></span>
      <span class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam eu fermentum dolor. Cras aliquet tempus elit ut eleifend. In commodo malesuada nisi non vulputate.</span>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```